# make UIImage conform to the NSCopying protocol

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nscopying

The question is quite simple, I need to have an UIImage conform to NSCopying protocol but I have absolutely no idea on where to start to achieve this.

Do you have any pointer to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've asked 5 questions, but not accepted any answers. This is not in keeping with the spirit of Stackoverflow, and will discourage others from taking the time to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
- (id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
{
    return [[UIImage allocWithZone: zone] initWithCGImage: self.CGImage];
}
```

Comment: I know this is pretty old but the solution presented here does not copy potential cap insets.

The thing is, that I found no way to find out whether there are cap insets or not. The UIImage documentation states, that the `capinsets` property will return `UIEdgeInsetsZero` when the image is not created via `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` (the whole image is streched in this case). But it also returns `..Zero` when someone explicitly SETS the `capInsets` to be Zero (the image is tiled in this case).

So I currently don't see any possibility to make UIImage compliant to NSCopying WITH capinsets.