# Using UIImageView as key in NSMutableDictionary to look up boolean

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

The title pretty much says it all. I want to create an NSMutableDictionary where I use UIImageViews to look up boolean values. Here's what it looks like:

My .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UIImageView *image1;
    UIImageView *image2;
    NSMutableDictionary *isUseable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *isUseable;
```

My .m file:

```
@synthesize image1, image2;
@synthesize isUseable

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    isUseable = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 @NO, image1,
                 @NO, image2,nil];
}

-(void)runEvents{
    if(some condition){
        [isUseable setObject:@YES forKey:(id)image1];
    }

    //Use it later:
    if(isUseable[image1]){
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

It compiles but when I run it I get an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I'm guessing that the problem lies with the fact that the NSDictionary class copies its keys. Is there a way to get a dictionary working in this case? If not, how should I set up a lookup like the one I want? Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that keys in an `NSDictionary` must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol and `UIImage` does not.

One solution would be to give each image a unique tag. Then use the image's tag as the key (after wrapping it in an `NSNumber`).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    isUseable = [ @{ @(image1.tag) : @NO, @(image2.tag) : @NO } mutableCopy];
}

-(void)runEvents {
    if(some condition) {
        [isUseable setObject:@YES forKey:@(image1.tag)];
    }

    //Use it later:
    if(isUseable[@(image1.tag)]) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Just add the code to see each image's `tag` property.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I got confused for a while until I realized that I have to set my own tag value (my fault for not reading your reply as carefully as I should have). I kind of like the hash suggestion below too since I wouldn't have to think about coming up with my own ids.

Answer (score 3):

rmaddy said it pretty right: an `NSDictionary` must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol and `UIImage` does not.

I recommend to use `@(image.hash)` as dictionary key. It's like a fingerprint of `UIImage`.

Comment: Using `hash` as the key may work. Keep in mind that it is possible for two images to have the same `hash` value. Though with only a few images the chances are pretty small.

Comment: It should be noted that `.hash` collisions are fairly common in Objective-c. They do not have the same collision resistance one is used to when dealing with something like SHA256. You can get the SHA256 of a UIImage if you need collision resistance. I've included an answer on how to do that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67627996/2057171

Answer (score 1):

Keys in `NSDictionaries` have to conform to `NSCopying` and `UIImageView` doesn't.
You will have to find a different key, or you could extend `UIImageView` to conform to `NSCopying`. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081177/make-uiimage-conform-to-the-nscopying-protocol) for how to do it with a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the raw data from the image (not a re-rendered PNG or JPG representation) and then run it through built in common-crypto to get SHA256 of the data, this will be your key.

Other answers suggest using the built in instance property `.hash` but it is prone to collision, and they end up happening frequently (We experienced a string collision in one of our apps and it caused a severe bug).

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

-(NSString *)keyFromImage:(UIImage *)image {

    NSData *imageData = (__bridge NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256((__bridge const void *)imageData, (CC_LONG)imageData.length, result);
    
    NSMutableString *imageHash = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [imageHash appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    
    return imageHash;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your object is managed you may be able to use its address in memory as a key (This applies to both UIImageView or UIImage since the general discussion on this question seems to revolve around either/or):

`myDictionary[@((intptr_t)myObject)] = myValue;`

Comment: I use this in the past when dealing with attaching images to a NSMutableString... I use the pointer to the NSTextAttachment as a key to reference the original HD source image to the thumbnail used in the NSTextAttachment so that I can display LQ image in text and HD image upon tap. Pointer value doesn't change since this all is within one UITextView